# Unknown function name in expression builder

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My expression looks like that - `@concat('/POC/View/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy'),'/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMMdd'),'/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMMddHHmmss'),'.parquet')` 
and azure claims that I use unknown function name pointing on formatDateTime nad utcnow(). I think that I've wrote that line accurately. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression you provided is for an Azure Data Factory pipeline, not a Data Flow. Functions `formatDateTime()`, `utcNow()` are not supported in dataflow.

[image]

For Data Flows, you can use the  `currentUTC()`  function to get the current UTC time and the  `toString()`  function to format the date and time as a string.

**Correct expression:**

Here is the correct expression:

```
concat('/POC/View/', toString(currentUTC(), 'yyyy'), '/', toString(currentUTC(), 'yyyyMMdd'), '/', toString(currentUTC(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'), '.parquet')
```

This expression will concatenate the specified strings and format the current UTC time as a string in the specified format.

Comment: Thank you, accepting your answer. I figured my problem out by "SetVariable" activity using @concat and formatDateTime(utcNow()) functions before dataflow activity